# How do I prevent the short description text from running together on a grouped product page?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, layout, template, grouped-products

As you can see on our grouped product page below, the text from the product short description is being run together in one paragraph. On Mac browsers, the text ends up being interspersed from different paragraphs.

[image: Screenshot]

Where can we control the layout of this type of page?

Comment: Sorry I don't follow, if you could add a screenshot, it would help.

Comment: The link I posted should show a page that exhibits the issue, but I'll add a screenshot of what I'm talking about.

Comment: you can add `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` right before text `How to upgrade`. This  might be in `view.phtml` file.